# I have 29 plots but I want them to be ordered into less rows, how do I do that on matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I have a for loop where I made 29 plots... how do I make the plots ordered side by side (say 4x7 plus one additional row with 1 plot) instead of all vertical?

```
for i in range(int(len(lsds_monthly)/24)):
    plt.plot(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24],lsds_monthly[i*24: (i+1)*24])
    plt.xticks(np.arange(min(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),max(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),.15), rotation=35)
    plt.grid()
    plt.title('LSDS Monthly Data')
    plt.show()
```

[image: how plots look now]

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=..., ncols=...)`?

Comment: hmm.. doesnt exactly work.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to plot using `ax` instead of `plt`:

```
for i in range(int(len(lsds_monthly)/24)):

    # add a new subplot
    ax = plt.subplot(5, 6, i+1)

    # plot on the subplot
    ax.plot(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24],lsds_monthly[i*24: (i+1)*24])

    # other formatting
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(min(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),max(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),.15), rotation=35)
    ax.grid()
    ax.title('LSDS Monthly Data')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! this really helps. In order to make the figure size bigger, do i do:  ax = plt.subplot(5, 6, i+1, figsize(15,10))

Comment: no, put `plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))` before and outside of `for` loop.